# powerwshell IF vs Switch

Tags: powershell

When retrieving the OS of a computer, I get a different result depending on whether i'm using an if statement or a switch:

```
if (((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName DT-04 Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption.ToString()) -match "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional") { "Found" } Else { "Not found" }
```

Result = Found

```
switch ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName DT-04 Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption.ToString()) { "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" { "Found" } Default { "Not Found" } }
```

Result = Not Found

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 7):

It's not `if` vs. `switch` that's making this different; it's the operators being used. In your `if` you're using `-match` but `switch` by default is using `-eq`.

By using `-match` you're doing a regular expression match, which will find that string anywhere in the source string. `-eq` will not. They should both be case insensitive.

You can modify `switch` to use regex or wildcard matching:

```
switch -regex ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName DT-04 Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption.ToString()) 
{ 
    "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" { "Found" } 
    Default { "Not Found" } 
}
```

or:

```
switch -wildcard ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName DT-04 Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption.ToString()) 
{ 
    "*Microsoft Windows 7 Professional*" { "Found" } 
    Default { "Not Found" } 
}
```

Alternatively, find out why your string is not an exact match and change your  literal. Which way you go will depend on your situation.

I'd be careful about the regex matching if you're not intending to use regex because it could be easy to inadvertently use special characters or invalidate your regex.

Comment: Thank you. it does in fact look like there is a blank space after the string that is returned I found it with:     
    
'"' + (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName DT-04 Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption.trim() + '"'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A correct and very good explained answer should be honoured by checking it as such.